# Find similarities in two lists of lists and retrieve indices

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists of lists including strings

```
L1 = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first'], ['list', 'of', 'lists'], ['with', 'strings']]

L2 = [['list', 'of', 'lists'], ['this', 'is', 'the', 'second'], ['which', 'looks', 'similar']]
```

Now I want to find the lists in `L1` where at least one of its strings exists in any of the lists in `L2` and then return the list index of that `L2` list. This index should then be used to append information from a third list to a fourth list,

```
L3 = [['3498'], ['3987'], ['0983']]

L4 = [[], [], []]
```

so that I in this example get

```
L4 = [['3987'], ['3498'], []]
```

I have used the following code

```
for i in range(len(L1)):
    for item in L2:
        if len(list(set(L1[i]).intersection(item)))>0:
            ind = L2.index(item)
            L4[i] = L3[ind]
```

which works fine, however, is slow for large lists. I am relatively new to Python and wonder if there is a more efficient why to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: `[L3[m] for i in L1 for m,j in enumerate(L2) if any([k in j for k in i])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to improve this code. First, pre-compute all the sets (including converting `L2`) rather than generating them on the fly. Second, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) to give you access to the index and values without having to subscript a list or call `index`. Finally, take advantage of the emptiness of a set intersection being true/false in a boolean context:

```
S1 = [set(l) for l in L1]
S2 = [set(l) for l in L2]
for i1, s1 in enumerate(S1):
    for i2, s2 in enumerate(S2):
        if s1.intersection(s2):
            L4[i1] = L3[i2]
            
print(L4)
```

Output:

```
[['3987'], ['3498'], []]
```

For your sample data this completes in about 40% less time.